# java.io.ReadObject intermittently taking extreme time

Tags: java, deserialization, latency

We are trying to deserialize a pretty hefty object with simple nested objects.  This normally takes approximately 5 - 10 ms.  However, recently we are experiencing random latency up to 3000ms during this call.  I can run requests over and over and get the exact same content length from the call but one out of every 20 is a huge lag hit.

When running a profiler it seems that the CPU time is eaten up in java.io.ReadObject.  I am really stumped as to what could cause such a jump in time taken given the calls are identical.

Any ideas would be hugely appreciated.

JVM has 4gb of ram running on centos with a 1.6 version.  There doesn't appear to be correlated GC events.

Comment: What's the source of the data? Has it already been read into memory?

Comment: Source of the data is coming from an http call.  The data **should** be fully in memory before the deserialization.  We are not using RMI.

Comment: @user954101 If it isn't GC, than you should meassure the response time of the web server and see whether network, webserver, dns or what causes the lag.

Answer (score 0):

Standard Java Serialization creates **a lot** of garbage.  If you are seeing spikes in the time to perform this it will be because a) it is waiting for IO (which can be any amount of time) or b) performing a minor or full GC.

I would run your application with

```
-verbosegc
```

to see when a full gc is being performed.  Otherwise you can use [jstat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html)

```
jstat -gccause 5s {process-id}
```

Most collections are stop-the-world so when a GC is being performed, the readObject will appear to have used lots of CPU when actually it was waiting for the GC to clean up some data.

When profiling your application I suggest enabling memory profiling.

All the same to have this sort of delays you must be de serializing a lot of data. To get a 3s delay it would typically take about 3 GB of garbage.  If its one per 20 requests, each request might be averaging 150 MB of garbage.

Perhaps its time to optimise your serialization.  You can get it to almost nothing but it takes more and more work to do this the lower you go. I would start by implementing readObject/writeObject as its the simplest change which could give you the most benefit.

Comment: There does not appear to be any correlation with garbage collections.  Additionally, on the rare occasion that they do appear in the same area the gc lasts about 50ms which doesn't account for the 3000 that the final latency number is.